# simplejson in Python throws value error

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine, decode

I've got a JSON string that I'm posting to my Python script. This is an example string:

```
{"uid":"1111111","method":"check_user"}
```

In my Python code I simply call `simplejson.loads( str )` where `str` is the JSON string from the request. The JSON string seems fine as when I print it at request time it's intact. However I get a ValueError:

```
Extra data: line 1 column 41 - line 1 column 48 (char 41 - 48)
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/_webapp25.py",
line 703, in __call__
    handler.post(*groups)   File "/Users/.../app/controller/api_controller.py", line 25, in post
    req = simplejson.loads( req )   File
"/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/django_0_96/django/utils/simplejson/__init__.py",
line 232, in loads
    return cls(encoding=encoding, **kw).decode(s)   File
"/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/django_0_96/django/utils/simplejson/decoder.py",
line 254, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
```

Any ideas what it may be? I've tried removing new lines, tabs and slashes from the string, even decoding it using `.decode('string_escape')`

Comment: The stacktrace here is not helpful. Try to minimize the scope, and probably it will help you to identify error. Or try to put prints to ensure that values are correct. If not helpful, try to eliminate dependencies, ideally put everything in single file and post again.

Comment: @RomanHwang Actually, that was all the info needed to answer the question. He explained that he knew that was the (printable part of the) string getting passed to JSON because he was `print`ing it, and he provided the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got some unprintable character in your string. I get the same error if I append a null byte to the end of the string, and `print`ing it doesn't show the problem:

```
>>> import json
>>> string = '{"uid":"1111111","method":"check_user"}\x00'
>>> print string
{"uid":"1111111","method":"check_user"}
>>> print repr(string)
'{"uid":"1111111","method":"check_user"}\x00'
>>> json.loads(string)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 369, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 39 - line 1 column 40 (char 39 - 40)
```

Print the `repr` of your string at request time and you should see it.

Comment: Awesome! So how'd I trim them off the end off the string?

Comment: @AhmedNuaman - It isn't necessarily at the end of the string. It's likely it's the same bad character doing it every time. I'd find out which one with `repr` and then just do `json.loads(mystring.replace('\x00', '')`, with whatever the bad character / character value is in place of `\x00`.

Comment: A better idea would be to track down the cause of the character(s) and either eliminate it, or use the correct encoding.